# Android - what is the best way of using Activities (best practice)

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm writing my first Android app and want to pick up good coding practices. I have an Activity which contains the following:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPressMe);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, SecondScreen.class));
            }
        });
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent("net.mysite.MediaPlayer.CLEARSCREEN"));
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".landingpage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="net.mysite.MediaPlayer.CLEARSCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abu,

The answer to your question depends largely on what you are trying to accomplish. Keep in mind that the other answers provided thus far have valuable input in regard to making your decision.

**The Android Philosophy**

Android is designed such that the User ultimately decides which applications take care of which tasks. Applications may overstep them, but should only do so if they are the only ones reasonably able to take care of that task **OR** if it is necessary for the functioning of the application as a whole.

An `Intent` marks the User's or the System's or an Application's desire to perform said task. Just because an `Intent` is made does not require that the User know or initiate it, though often it is best. However, if the Intent is hidden to the User, one might question whether it should be an Intent at all. This is something that is still being worked out by the development community and there are advocates both for and against the practice.

**Static Class Intents**

> startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, SecondScreen.class));

These should be used when you cannot trust another application to handle your desired Task effectively. These kinds of tasks should also be "hidden" from the User, as the User may not care what is happening or who is doing it, so long as it gets done. Additionally, they should only be used for stable code that is not subject to changes. As Snicolas stated (and I personally agree):

> Classes can vary in the life of an app.

**Action String Intents**

> startActivity(new Intent("net.mysite.MediaPlayer.CLEARSCREEN"));

These should be used whenever possible. However, they should only be used when the Task can be performed by another application without destabilizing your own application. The Action String can be designed in such a way that it is rare enough to not be called by anyone else, but understand that an Action will prompt the User if more than one Application can handle it.

Analogize the idea similar to: "I use Microsoft Office for Databases and Word Processing, but when I want a Spreadsheet, I use Open Office". Both provide compatible results, but one is preferred for one reason or another. This works because Excel is not required for Word or Access to work correctly. Neither are Open Office's equivalents required for any other working part. They are all installed together but work independantly because they work with different resources and data entirely.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 2):

The first way described is best used within your application, the other is used for other application to call your activity.

Comment: IOW, *only* use the second approach when you are expressly seeking other applications (or the OS) to start your activity. This then becomes part of your application's public API, and you will need to keep this consistent and supported for the rest of time. If you have an activity that should only ever be launched by your own code, use your first approach.

Comment: `The first way described is bet used` : i am assuming you mean to say "BEST" ?, i am still not clear with the answer and still confused which one is used for the best practice... can you elobrate your answer little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to use a static class name to call an intent. Classes can vary in the life of an app. Later, if you decide that this activity should change for another class, you would just have to change it in one and only one place if you use the AndroidManifest way.

Also, defining this kind of configuration provides other apps with a way to call your activities to get a service done. And that's the actual power of android to let apps communicate through intents.

Comment: you meant to say second option is best to use?